# ExtJS ComboBox when enters manual value it clear the input and not add/change it

Tags: extjs

My Code look like this:

```
this.assignFieldEditor = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            id: 'assignFieldEditor',
            name: "assignFieldEditor",
            fieldLabel: 'Assign Field',
            store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
                fields: ["name"],
                data: [....someListThatRenderedByRequest]
            }),
            editable: true,
            valueField: "name",
            displayField: "name",
            mode: 'local',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            width: 180
        });


    return new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        region: "center",
        colModel: new Ext.grid.SecureColumnModel([
.
.
.
.

            {
                header: "Assign Field",
                dataIndex: "assignField",
                sortable: true,
                editor: this.assignFieldEditor,
                renderer: this.typeRenderer(this.assignFieldEditor, "assignField"),
                width: 180,
                editable: true,
                readOnly: false,
            },
.
.
.
.
        ]),
        store: this.store,
        clicksToEdit: 2,
        sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),

    });
```

and when I enter manual value that not exist in the list, it clear the input, so when I try to save, the modified inputs are nothing.
for example I have in the list: [['type'],['age']] , and i'm trying to insert new value like 'gender', it not exist on the list, and when I enter it, the input is cleared automatically so cant even save it.

gif example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these to the combobox configuration after `editable: true`:

```
...
editable: true,
// add these
forceSelection: false,
autoSelect: false,
...
```

Comment: Not working unfurtunatly. when I enter the text and then move to the next input, it cleared

Comment: Could you create a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate it? From the gif it seems that the combo is re-created.

Comment: Hey, It was something wrong with my code.
I had a Render function that was overrriding the value.
Thanks!